# How to remove tags using RegexTokenizer() in Spark/Scala ML?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have a a feature column that has HTML tags in it. I would like to remove all tags. 
An example of one row of data from column "body" is as follows:

```
"<p>Are questions related to and similar products on-topic?</p>"
```

I would like the output after using RegexTokenizer() to be as follows:

```
"are questions related to and similar products on-topic?"
```

Here is what I have started:

```
val regexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer()
  .setInputCol("body")
  .setOutputCol("removedTags")
  .setPattern("")
```

I think I need to fix the .setPattern() but unsure of how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you may not have any other `<` or `>` in your strings, maybe,

```
<[^>]+>
```

replaced with an empty string might be working OK to some extent, [otherwise it'd fail](https://regex101.com/r/kC9OmK/1/).

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Msy6Sj/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Msy6Sj/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---